# Realtek rtl8188fu Wifi adapters are too slow

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers, internet-speed

I have an rtl8188fu wifi adapter and I have installed driver for it from https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu . My problem is that the network speed is too slow. I have tried the wifi adapter on another Windows computer and it was fast. But when I use it on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, it is very slow. It hardly reaches 3 Kilobits per second. With this I came to know that the problem was not with the adapter itself, but with the driver or the Operating System.

I have tested it with Google, https://speedtest.net, speedtest cli, fast.com, etc. It's really weird that it reaches more than 50 Kilobits per second on windows while it cannot get more than 3 Kilobits per second on Ubuntu. Help me on this problem.

Comment: If there is not a good Ubuntu driver for this card, you may need to try a different wireless card that does have drivers for Ubuntu.

Comment: I generally recommend against Realtek Wi-Fi adapters because there are a large number of different chips, each of which needs a custom driver, and generally the performance and reliability of the drivers is poor at first and takes a couple years to mature.